# Macbook restarts because of kernel panic

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic

Since a year ago my Macbook Pro (13-inch, late 2011, El Capitan) restarts and shows panic reports. I changed the hard drive and installed a Samsung SSD. Lately, the kernel panics are more frequent. Also, it doesn't startup/boot properly at times. I formatted the SSD and repaired the SSD with apps such as DiskWarrior. The panic report says:

```
    Anonymous UUID:       5310EA1F-CA7C-4FBD-B326-9092404CA8A6

Wed Jun 29 23:18:01 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8025dce5fa): Kernel trap at 0xffffff8025d60f50, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff0038b86550, CR3: 0x00000000012a004e, CR4: 0x00000000000626e0
RAX: 0xffffff8039b15b80, RBX: 0x00000000dc00bd80, RCX: 0x0000700000531000, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff9130f83de0, RBP: 0xffffff9130f83f00, RSI: 0x0000002726c6c29a, RDI: 0xffffff8039b15b80
R8:  0xffff000000000000, R9:  0xffff800000000000, R10: 0x000ffffffffff000, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0xffffff803b108860, R13: 0x00007000004ae000, R14: 0xffffff0038b86540, R15: 0xffffff80397789b0
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff8025d60f50, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff0038b86550, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9130f83a70 : 0xffffff8025cdab12 
0xffffff9130f83af0 : 0xffffff8025dce5fa 
0xffffff9130f83cd0 : 0xffffff8025dec463 
0xffffff9130f83cf0 : 0xffffff8025d60f50 
0xffffff9130f83f00 : 0xffffff8025d563dc 
0xffffff9130f83f30 : 0xffffff7fa699e76a 
0xffffff9130f83f60 : 0xffffff80262286a1 
0xffffff9130f83fb0 : 0xffffff8025decc66 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.kec.pthread(1.0)[39D0B4EB-B7F4-3891-96C2-F8B886656C8A]@0xffffff7fa699d000->0xffffff7fa69a9fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: coreaudiod

Mac OS version:
15F34

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.5.0: Tue Apr 19 18:36:36 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.50.21~8/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 7E7B0822-D2DE-3B39-A7A5-77B40A668BC6
Kernel slide:     0x0000000025a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8025c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8025b00000
System model name: MacBookPro8,1 (Mac-94245B3640C91C81)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 64680328040
last loaded kext at 38559693927: com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor 1.9.5d0 (addr 0xffffff7fa846c000, size 36864)
loaded kexts:
com.globaldelight.driver.Boom2Device    1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver   1.0.2d2
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.22.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   274.9
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.12.8
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   274.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   274.9
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.12.8
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    10.0.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.4.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.6
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.4
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1040.1.1a6
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.8
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.9
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.1.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.12.8
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 274.9
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 274.9
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.4
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
Model: MacBookPro8,1, BootROM MBP81.0047.B2C, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2,4 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.68f99
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435435313236344246313333392E43313646
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435435313236344246313333392E43313646
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.5f3 17904, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB, 500,11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Thanks!

Comment: It says `BSD process name corresponding to current thread: coreaudiod` and `com.globaldelight.driver.Boom2Device    1.1`.  Do you have any third-party audio devices or drivers?

Comment: Yes. It's an app called "Boom". I will uninstall it and see what happens.

Comment: Boom2 is a known crasher, for sure.

Comment: @Tetsujin Just wondering, is Boom like some sort of malware, is it just poorly written, or is it something else entirely?

Comment: It's legit but I'm not convinced it's well-written. I've seen a few people with kernel panics since they installed it.

Comment: @fbara your solution worked. I uninstalled the app and the kernel panics stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says `BSD process name corresponding to current thread: coreaudiod` and `com.globaldelight.driver.Boom2Device 1.1`.

Do you have any third-party audio devices or drivers?  If so, try uninstall ingredients them/it and see if that helps.